# Constructors vs Assignment c++

Tags: c++, class-constructors

I am having a huge disconnect while trying to figure out constructors. My question is this: Are constructors with initialization lists replacing the set methods of a class?
For example:

```
Class Rock
{
private: 
    double Weight;
public:
    void setWeight(double)
    { Weight = wei; }
    double getWeight()
    { return Weight; }
    double calcWeight()
    { return Weight *= 2; } 
}
```

Would using a constructor with initialization list that looks something like: `Rock::Rock(double): Weight(w) {}` replace using the set method?

Comment: Constructors are used to do *exactly* as their name implies: construct objects of the specified type. Setters likewise do as their name implies: set member values of *constructed* (past tense) objects. The times to use one, the other, both, or even neither, vary dependent on the architecture and workflow of your program.

Comment: No. The constructor is called for new objects, the setter sets the value on an existing object. It would, however, prevent you from having to construct the object then set the value later.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors and so called *setter* methods are two distinct things and are used in different contexts. Unlike setters, constructors may be **used implicitly** (e.g. a default constructor is used when we have a standard library container with elements of the class type), **when an object is being instantiated**.

```
std::vector<Rock> vec_of_rocks; // Will contain default initialized Rock objects
```

Moreover, constructors allow us to control how an object will be instantiated when we copy-construct it (as in `Rock b(a);`), and in few other scenarios.

Meanwhile, a user of the class can use setter methods to **modify existing objects explicitly**. Most often *setter* method is used to provide safe and controlled way to modify some `private` data member.

```
// First check for the weight to be non-negative, then set it
void Rock::setWeight(const double &d)
    { if (d >= 0) Weight = d; else Weight = 0; } 

Rock r_object; // Default initialized object r_object (by default constructor) 
r_object.setWeight(3.14); // In the user-code, we modify default initialized value
```

Note, we can intorduce constructors which initialize objects with specified values, via constructor member initializer lists.

```
Rock::Rock(const double &d) : Weight(d) {} // Constructor that takes an argument, not a default one
Rock r_object_2(1,12); // Uses the defined above constructor, not a default one
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed response.

Comment: @Michael410 you're welcome, it's always good to refresh the memory! Please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted one, if you consider one as such.

Answer (score 0):

Setters and constructors serve completely different purposes, and one never "replaces" the other.

Constructors set up the initial state of instances, and setters allow you to change that state after construction.

That being said, if you find yourself doing something like the following:

```
Rock rock;
rock.setWeight(3);
```

Then what you are *actually* doing is setting the initial state of the rock. In that case, then yes, a constructor taking the weight as a parameter is preferable.

However, notice that this is a distinction that happens at the point where the class is **used**, not when it is **declared**.

Comment: awesome, thank you for the response. I still have a lot of learning to do.

Comment: @Michael410 you are most welcome. Always glad to shed some light. :)